# How can I prevent closing app when I double-click fast in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onitemclicklistener

Below is the double-check method in `Utils.kt`

```java
var mLastClickTime: Long = 0
fun isDoubleClicked(): Boolean {
    if(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
        Log.d(TAG, "double clicked")
        return true
    }
    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
    return false
}
```

And Below is usage of `isDoubleClicked()` method.

```java
memoAdapter.itemClick = object : MemoAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
   override fun onItemClick(memo: Memo, view: View) 

   if (isDoubleClicked()) return

   val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, DetailMemoActivity::class.java)
   intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ID, memo.id)
   intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TITLE, memo.title)
   intent.putExtra(EXTRA_CONTENT, memo.content)
   intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PHOTO, memo.photos)
   intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TIMESTAMP, memo.timestamp)
   startActivityForResult(intent, EDIT_MEMO_REQUEST)
   }
}
```

when I click twice not so fast but less than in 1000ms, the Log message "double clicked" shown well.

**BUT**

when I click twice **very fast**, my app hide into Android Background, as if I had pressed the home button.

And when I reopen the app, the method `startActivityForResult(~~,~~)` seems to have been called well. I mean, `DetailMemoActivity` is started.

How can I prevent closing app when I double-click fast?

Comment: Do you mean the app crashed?

Comment: @einUsername there is no any error message in Logcat about app crash, and this is the only warning message

[W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7cde103010 disconnect failed]

Comment: So if (isDoubleClicked()) return basicly means exit the method if it was double clicked, right? Try if (!isDoubleClicked()) return or use some { and }

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a double click method like this.

```
private long timestamp = 0;
private void doubleClickListener(){
    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp;
    if (elapsedTime < 500 && elapsedTime > 100){
        Log.d("TAG", "multi tap detected. elapsed time: " + elapsedTime);

        timestamp = 0;
        return;
    }
    timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
};
```

Comment: really appreciate for your answer but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Does it just do nothing? You have to call this method from the normal onClick method.

Comment: sure I did it. but same thing happen to me

Comment: Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Maybe in the DetailMemoActivity.

Comment: @ einUsername Yeah I think so too.. ok now, I m gonna make all of the DetailMemoActivity code to comment and erase them singly until find out the problem. Thanks a lot! :)